# What makes Android main thread keeps on running unlike other threads

Tags: android, java-threads

How the main thread keeps on running unlike other threads which terminates after executing their task.?

Comment: Android's main thread is an event loop.

Comment: @Dave Can you please explain more in detail

Comment: it has `android.os.Looper` associated with it

Comment: @pslink thanks, can you please shore some link elaborating this? It would be very helpful?

Comment: sure: [Understanding Android Core: Looper, Handler, and HandlerThread](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a)